# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_backend.todo'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Just started a fresh Django Rest framework project and I'm getting stuck on importing a view (TodoView) in urls.py

This is a completely fresh project, all I did was add the model, view and now attempting to add the url.

```
File "C:\Users\Simon\Documents\GitHub\tradingjournal\django_backend\django_backend\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    from django_backend.todo.views import TodoView
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_backend.todo'
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework import routers

from django_backend.todo.views import TodoView

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'todos', TodoView, 'todo')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from rest_framework import viewsets

from django_backend.todo.models import Todo
from django_backend.todo.serializers import TodoSerializer


class TodoView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer
    queryset = Todo.objects.all()
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for django_backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'n3^zfbj#c&i-9v^8q(%iox!kuy@gy2liy-1b+)q21-g&nwezf('

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'todo',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I tried changing django_backend.todo.views to todo.views but as you can see in the screenshot it's not recognized:

[image]

Comment: `from todo.views import TodoView`, etc. Don't use the project name in the imports, only the app names.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Check the screenshot I added. Views cannot be found if I use todo.views.

Comment: That is just your IDE not knowing where the sources root is (if you actually run the project that wouldn't give an error), since you are using pycharm you can set that by: `Right click on the project directory i.e. django_backend (on the project structure on the left side) > Mark Directory As > Sources root`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks, that fixed it!! If you could post an answer I can resolve this question and give you internet points

Answer (score 1):

In a Django project the directory name of the project really doesn't matter in the code so instead of

```
from django_backend.todo.views import TodoView
```

you need to be writing:

```
from todo.views import TodoView
```

Next you see pycharm complaining that this is not a valid import while in fact it actually is (can be seen by actually running the project). Why does this happen? It is because it considers your projects root directory (i.e. there is likely a directory above `django_backend`) as the sources root and hence is unable to resolve your imports. To solve this you just need to set it as the Sources root by following these steps:

1. Right click on the project directory i.e. django_backend (on the project structure on the left side)
2. Select the option "Mark Directory As"
3. Click "Sources root"